# Get HttpStatusCode 504 ( DNS Name Not Found ) in .Net Core 2.1 and Upper Version

Tags: iis, httpclient, http-status-code-504, .net-core-2.1, .net-core-3.0

I was create simple project with `.netCore 2.0` and send `HttpRequest` with `HttpClient`, that is working well.

But, when I'm migrating from `.netCore 2.0` to upper version ( e.g: `.NetCore 2.1` or `.netCore 3.0` ) this Code is not working.

My Code is:

```
public async Task<bool> IsValid()
    {
        string url = "http://api.domain.com/...";
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
               { "param1", "value1" },
               { "param2", "value2" }
            };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var post = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
        if (post.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I expect the output of `httpResponse` to bo `HttpStatusCode.OK`. but the actual output is `HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout`.

I found that:
If I run `API server` ( `http://api.domain.com/` ) in `IIS` of `windows server 2012`, all requests is working well.
But When I Use `IIS` of `Windows 8`, only `HttpRequest` with `ASP.NET Core sdk 2.0` is working and others not working.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How are you running this? .NET Core Console? ASP.NET Core? What SDK's are you using? What are you using to debug this?

Comment: I use .Net core sdk 2.1 in ASP.NET Core application.
(I also Test in asp.net core 2.2 and 3.0 but not working).

I call this method from controller.

Comment: Have you enabled `Development time IIS support`? We have had issues in the past as well where the SDK hasn't installed the runtime correctly so it works in development but not when we deploy to a site with IIS

Comment: I test this method in Developmet Mode.

Comment: I test this method in Developmet Mode, and `IIS` Complete installed in `Windows 8`.

But `Development time IIS support` not installed in `vs Installer`, this feature is optional.
I install this feature and test again.
thanks for help.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi Tubs.
I install those features in `vs 2019` and test again.
But that is not working.
I still have that error.

Comment: I think that is related to `iis setup` in `win 8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has finally  been resolved.

This problem was related to the `network and proxy` settings in `my network`.

I realize when `api server` be in `internet network`, that is working well. but when `api server` to be used in local network, Because of using the `proxy` in my network, all 
requests was encountered with error `504` (unless the request was sending with `.netCore sdk 2.0` ).

It should be noted I had added this line `192.168.11.125 api.domain.com` to `host` file in Directory `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.
and also, I had added Follow Exceptions:
`192.168.11.125 api.domain.com`
from path:

`Control Panel > Network and Internet > Internet Option > Connections Tab > Lan Settings > Advanced > Exceptions panel`

But that's not working.

When I picked up the check of `Use a proxy server for your lan ...` in `Local Area Network (LAN) Settings` form, all requests working well.

Of course, this question remains that, why `The same request` is working with .netcore sdk 2.0 ?

what is difference between sending request with `.netCore sdk 2.0` and (`.netCore sdk 2.1` or `.netCore sdk 2.2` or `.netCore sdk 3.0`)???!!!

Good luck.